# efficient way of getting k equal values in a row

Tags: c

i'm trying to find a subsequence of of k equal elemts as in
int arr = [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
k_in_row(arr, 5,3) will return true as there a k equal elements in a row
i have written this code and i want to make it more efficient to O(n + k)
and i was wondering how i can do that, as the code below is with the time efficiency O(n^2)

```
bool k_in_row(const int arr[], int len, int k) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
      if (i + j < len && arr[i] == arr[i+j]) {
        ++count;
      } 
    }
    if (count == k) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code (explanation given in the code comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> // for built-in C boolean types

int k_in_row(int arr[], int size, int seq) {
    // to keep remember the counter even after end of the function
    static int counter;

    // checking if the previous array is equal to the current array
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        // count if they're equal
        if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) counter++;
        // otherwise, reset
        else counter = 1;

    // if the sequence is equal to the counted number after end of the loop
    // then return true, otherwise, false
    return (seq == counter) ? true : false;
}

int main(void) {
    // the example array
    int arr[] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int row_len = 5;

    bool in_row = k_in_row(arr, len, row_len);

    // if it's in row, then print "sequential" otherwise "Another time..."
    if (in_row)
        printf("Yes, it's sequential.\n");
    else
        printf("Another time better, friend.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

It'll output something like:

```
Yes, it's sequential.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops for this.

Start the counter at 1 and start with the second element in the list.  Then check if the current element is the same as the previous element.  If so, increment the counter.  If not, set it to 1.  Return true if `count` becomes equal to `k`.

Comment: i was thinking of decrementing k each time the element is same with the next element,and the putting another if statement to see if its k = 0 if it is then that returns true, is that time complexity O(n+k)?

Comment: @samm That's similar to what I stated, just counting in the opposite direction.  You need to keep track of the original value of `k` if you don't get a match however.  But again, you only need one loop.